# How to use data as key in Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my current Firebase database configuration where I want to use username as key and CurrentUser.ID as the value.

I tried to use string interpolation but I got some error.

```
function updateExistingUserRoot(username) {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/ExistingUser`).push({
      `${username}`: currentUser.uid
    })
  }
}
```

I understand firebase generates an unique key every time data is being pushed but I would like to stay with the current configuration.

**Update 1**

I have changed to using **set** but the error persists.

```
function updateExistingUserRoot(username) {
  const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
  firebase.database().ref(`/ExistingUser`).set({
    `${username}`: currentUser.uid
  });
}
```

***The error: expected property assignment.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given by the two gentlemen are correct but I had to tweaked a little bit to get it working.

Here's the code

```
firebase.database().ref(`/ExistingUser/${username}`).set({
   userID: currentUser.uid
 }).then(() => console.log('Set existing user done'))
   .catch((error) => console.log(error.message))
```

Answer (score 0):

For the configuration you want, you should rather be using `set` or `update` methods to save or update your data.

```
firebase.database().ref(`/ExistingUser`).set({
      `${username}`: currentUser.uid
})
```

This way, your data gets saved in the `username` node which will be mapped with the user's `uid`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a user with a specific key, you should remove the `push` method (that creates a unique key) and use something like:

```
firebase.database().ref(`/ExistingUser` + userKey).set({
    username: value...
  });
```

Everything in Firebase is an url.

```
https://testxxx.firebaseio.com/xxx/ExistingUser
```

If you want to create a user with a key of KEY1 as a child at this location you would have:

```
https://testxxx.firebaseio.com/xxx/ExistingUser/KEY1
```